# Simplest way to get the difference (amount of days) of two dates in Java 8 as a Short primitive type

Tags: java, long-integer, short, date-difference

For example the difference between `24.05.2017` and `31.05.2017`
would be `7`

Am I on the right path here?

```
private short differenceOfBillingDateAndDueDate(Date billingDate, Date dueDate) {

    LocalDate billingLocalDate = billingDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

    LocalDate dueLocalDate = dueDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

    return (short) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(billingLocalDate,dueLocalDate);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine - but as you're using System Timezone anyway you could skip that. It's also fine to use Instant directly - no need to convert into LocalDate first. You can also skip the local variables and perform the Date to Instant conversion right away:

```
public static short differenceOfBillingDateAndDueDate(Date billingDate, Date dueDate) {
    return (short)ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
              billingDate.toInstant()
             ,dueDate.toInstant());
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
public static short differenceOfBillingDateAndDueDate(Date billingDate, Date dueDate) {
    return (short)billingDate.toInstant().until(dueDate.toInstant(), ChronoUnit.DAYS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are on the right way!

Since you are asking for java8 you can use LocalDate  and ChronoUnit

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(2000, Month.JANUARY, 1);
long period = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(today, birthday);

System.out.println(period);
```